# Jasmine + AngularJS: How to test $rootScope.$broadcast being called with arguments?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, yeoman-generator-angular

I am trying to write a unit test that verifies that `$rootScope.$broadcast('myApiPlay', { action : 'play' });` is called.

Here is the myapi.js

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('MyApi', function ($rootScope) {
    var api = {};
    api.play = function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('myApiPlay', { action : 'play' });
    }
    return api;
});
```

And here is my Unit Test:

```
describe('Service: MyApi', function () {

    // load the service's module
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    // instantiate service
    var MyApi;
    var rootScope;

    beforeEach(function () {
        inject(function ($rootScope, _MyApi_) {
            MyApi = _MyApi_;
            rootScope = $rootScope.$new();
        })
    });
    it('should broadcast to play', function () {
        spyOn(rootScope, '$broadcast').andCallThrough();
        rootScope.$on('myApiPlay', function (event, data) {
            expect(data.action).toBe('play');
        });
        MyApi.play();
        expect(rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith('myApiPlay');
    });
});
```

Here is the error i'm getting while running `grunt test`:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7) Service: MyApi should broadcast to pause FAILED
        Expected spy $broadcast to have been called with [ 'myApiPlay' ] but it was never called.
```

I have also tried with `expect(rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalled()` and I am having a similar error: `Expected spy $broadcast to have been called.`.

I would like to verify that that method has actually been called with the right parameters.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you just need to switch the order? You might need to expect before it's actually called, in your case you call it, then expect it. You could also confirm that call count.

Comment: I switched the order, same error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason your tests are not passing is because you are spying on the wrong $broadcast function. In your beforeEach setup, you ask to have the $rootScope injected and then you create a child scope by calling $rootScope.$new().

The return value from $rootScope.$new() is no longer the rootScope but a child of the root scope.

```
beforeEach(function () {
    //inject $rootScope
    inject(function ($rootScope, _MyApi_) {
        MyApi = _MyApi_;
        //create a new child scope and call it root scope
        rootScope = $rootScope.$new();
        //instead don't create a child scope and keep a reference to the actual rootScope
        rootScope = $rootScope;
    })
});
```

In your play function, you are calling $broadcast on the $rootScope but in your test you are spying on a child of $rootScope.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('myApiPlay', { action : 'play' });
```

So to wrap it up, remove the call to $rootScope.$new() and just spy on the $rootScope the injector has given you. The $rootScope provided to your unit test is the same $rootScope provided to your API service so you should be spying directly on the $rootScope.

Check out the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/wN0m8no2FlKf3BZKjC4k?p=preview

Comment: this is fine for `expect(rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith('myApiPlay', { action : 'play' });` but this expect is not called: `rootScope.$on('myApiPlay', function (event, data) { expect(data.action).toBe('play');});`

Comment: you don't need that test. That test is testing the angular framework and not the business logic itself. You can assume that when you call rootScope.$broadcast, the listeners setup using $on will be called correctly because thats how AngularJS works

Comment: all you really need to test is that $rootScope.$broadcast was called with the expected parameters

Comment: it was good to read the explanation, i saw couple of examples about this, but without explaining about that `$rootScoop.new();`

Answer (score 1):

It will be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/17227264/2594499
Your test isn't clear. Avoid using "expect" in conditions, callbacks and things like this.
If your condition won't be true, you've got test without assertion.

It'll be better to use second parameter of function:

```
.toHaveBeenCalledwith('someEvent', someObj);
```

Comment: Hello, I am doing like you are saying, but the unit test says that it is not called. I am testing that when calling `MyApi.play()` is called the message is broadcasted.